# n-grams from text in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, text-mining

I am looking to create n-grams from text column in PostgreSQL. I currently split(on white-space) data(sentences) in a text column to an array.

`enter code here`select regexp_split_to_array(sentenceData,E'\s+') from tableName

Once I have this array, how do I go about:

- Creating a loop to find n-grams, and write each to a row in another table

Using unnest I can obtain all the elements of all the arrays on separate rows, and maybe I can then think of a way to get n-grams from a single column, but I'd loose the sentence boundaries which I wise to preserve.

Sample SQL code for PostgreSQL to emulate the above scenario

```
create table tableName(sentenceData  text);

INSERT INTO tableName(sentenceData) VALUES('This is a long sentence');

INSERT INTO tableName(sentenceData) VALUES('I am currently doing grammar, hitting this monster book btw!');

INSERT INTO tableName(sentenceData) VALUES('Just tonnes of grammar, problem is I bought it in TAIWAN, and so there aint any englihs, just chinese and japanese');

select regexp_split_to_array(sentenceData,E'\\s+')   from tableName;

select unnest(regexp_split_to_array(sentenceData,E'\\s+')) from tableName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html): "The pg_trgm module provides functions and operators for determining the similarity of text based on trigram matching, as well as index operator classes that support fast searching for similar strings."